Equivalent of Stata's Prob > chi2 in Python
I did a logistic regression analysis in Stata using the command logit and got a Prob>chi2 value, it´s a value that I didn't get in Python logistic regression summary using [Logit][https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html] command
I been searching for alternatives in librarys like scipy.stats, but I can't get the same value
Statistics are not my speciality, so i don't know if I'm doing something wrong, I was hoping someone can tell me if there some equivalent in Python to get that value

Hi.  You could maybe increase the chance that somebody can help you if you can edit your question to include some simple toy data, the Stata command and the key part of its output for the toy data, and what you have tried in Python.

Thanks for the advice (still new on this), i tried to do what you say, hope it's enought

My suggestion would be to show a table with 4 or 5 rows of data ("cases" in Stata), and maybe two variables.  Then show the actual Stata syntax (or a screen shot of the dialog box) that produces the value you want, for the toy data.  Show the actual part of the Stata output that you are interested in.  Then show what script.stats you are trying, what you get from it, and if there is any doubt explain how that differs from what you want to get.
